# ValueError: Cannot use numpy array of type XXX for string tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-lite

I had created a text-classification model using the pre-trained model from Tensorflow Hub, the summary of the model is like this

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer_5 (KerasLayer)   (None, 128)               112461824 
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 16)                2064      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 112,463,905
Trainable params: 2,081
Non-trainable params: 112,461,824
_________________________________________________________________
```

Then I convert this model to **tflite** format with `tf-nightly` and it was a success. After that I wanted to do test the tflite model with my own texts in python. Here is my code:

```py
# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(r'./model_tf_filterComments.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get input and output tensors.
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

input_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]["index"]
output_index = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]["index"]

input_data = ["You are extremely strong man, please don't give up!"]
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data) ## This line causes the error
```

However, I cannot use my text to predict using the tflite model as it's always error when I set the tensor for input_details. The error details are shown below:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-b32325c64589> in <module>()
      1 input_data = ["You are extremely strong man, please don't give up!"]
----> 2 interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in set_tensor(self, tensor_index, value)
    585       ValueError: If the interpreter could not set the tensor.
    586     """
--> 587     self._interpreter.SetTensor(tensor_index, value)
    588 
    589   def resize_tensor_input(self, input_index, tensor_size, strict=False):

ValueError: Cannot use numpy array of type 32663 for string tensor.
```

When I try to use `int` inside the array for the input, another error pops up as it expects the type `STRING`, and also when I try to put just string (without array brackets), it expects an array with 1 dimension.

So How can I input the text to my model for the prediction?

Comment: Strange does the model have an inbuilt tokenizer?

Comment: Can you share the tensorflow hub link

Comment: Here it is: https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-id-dim128/2

Answer (score 0):

Your input data must be on numpy array.

You can try this one:

```
input_data = numpy.array(["You are extremely strong man, please don't give up!"])
```